# slow SQL query SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: mysql

help solve the problem often occurs that a slow query.

```
# Query_time: 12.519347  Lock_time: 0.000057 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 98260
SET timestamp=1464192549;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  
  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Медвен%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Медвен%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Медвен%')))  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Медвен%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

how to fix it?

Comment: provide your table schema. do you have index against `(wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date)` ? you can try to change  `LIKE '%Медвен%'` to `LIKE 'Медвен%'`

Comment: Please consider posting results of SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_posts and results of SHOW INDEX FROM wp_posts to be considered with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to leverage a typical BTREE index with a LIKE clause that is not a prefix match (i.e. does not match the starting at the beginning of the string). `LIKE sometext%` will use the BTREE index while `LIKE %sometext%` will not be able to use this index.

You also have a similar LIKE clause in your ORDER BY, which is going to further compound the problem for sorting.

As such, I don't think there is much hope in trying to ultimately optimize the query in it's current form, other then maybe getting some gains be removing the ORDER BY condition.

It looks like what you are trying to do (search across multiple columns with a single term), would be better accomplished with a full text search.  See MySQL documentation here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Full text search leverages a specific type of index (a `FULLTEXT` index) which is optimized for this sort of search pattern.